# How to I remove a sub-document that is in a collection?

Tags: mongodb

mongo> db.users.findOne({username: 'foo'});

```
   {
    "__v" : 266,
    "_id" : ObjectId("50752b5f00a0f5ab64000002"),
    "followers" : [
            ObjectId("505e2f1de888c7d701000001"),
            ObjectId("506146fe72c0280723000001"),
            ObjectId("50752b5f00a0f5ab64000002"), //remove this
            ObjectId("50752b5f00a0f5ab64000002") //remove this
    ],
```

I want to remove the last two items in followers[] collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this (if you are *sure* they are the last two):

```
db.users.update({"_id" : ObjectId("50752b5f00a0f5ab64000002")}, {$pop: {followers:1}});
db.users.update({"_id" : ObjectId("50752b5f00a0f5ab64000002")}, {$pop: {followers:1}});
```

[`$pop`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pop) will remove the last element of an array.

However, if you need to remove specific ids from the list regardless of where they are, you can use [`$pull`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pull), or [`$pullAll`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pullAll) if you want to remove several at once.